# Loading the application manifest in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, com, clickonce

I have a [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) application deployed to a virtual machine, Windows 7 32-bit. This application uses some [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) components so to get the application working I have created manifests for both the COM assembly and the the application, i.e.

application1.exe and
application1.exe.manifest

comAssembly1.dll and
comAssembly1.x.manifest

Following information from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx).

To ensure the application is working, I have run regsvr32 on the COM assembly and all is OK. I then un-registered the assembly and was hoping that all would continue to work. Sadly, it is not the case.

My first port of call was to check my manifests. These match the article referenced above as well as others I have read. So I wanted to check if the manifest was being loaded. I have [Process Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Monitor) running and have put a filter on to show only access of files named "application1.exe.manifest", and I don't see any. Having a bit of a google I don't seem to be able to find anywhere that says when then manifest is loaded or by which process.

Have any of you had this problem before? If so, did you discover the cause?
Or is there some magic switch I need in my ClickOnce manifests to tell it to use a manifest file?

And for my own information, when would you expect to see you applications manifest being accessed?

Answer (score 1):

A separate .manifest file will only be used by Windows if the executable doesn't contain an embedded manifest.  Problem is that any C# executable already has one.  A simple one that's auto-generated by the compiler, it declares the program compatible with UAC.

Project + Add New Item, pick the Application Manifest File item template.  It will open in the editor, showing those UAC entries.  Move your reg-free COM manifest entries into this one and deploy your app without the .manifest files.

Comment: hi thanks for the quick response, in the case of my application project I have selected create application without an embedded manifest. I was under the impression this would mean my new manifest would be used. Am I incorrect in this assumption?

Comment: How do you even do that?  There's no compile option for that, you'd have to pass an empty RES file with the /win32res compile option.  I recommend you use the solution I described.

Comment: In VS, right click on project, select properties in the application tab under Icon and manifest select option "Create application without a manifest", as per [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3tc5xx.aspx)